# laravel 5.3: ErrorException in UrlGenerator.php line 314: Route [produce.reduceByOne] not defined

Tags: php, laravel

Here my routes code in web.php

```
Route::get('/reduce/{id}',[
    'uses'  => 'ProductController@getReduceByOne',
    'as'    => 'product.reduceByOne'
]);
```

Controller method:

```
public function getReduceByOne($id)
{
    $oldCart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : null;
    $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
    $cart->reduceByOne($id);

    Session::put('cart', $cart);
    return redirect()->route('product.shoppingCart');
}
```

View Pages

```
<a href="{{ route('produce.reduceByOne') }}">Reduce by 1</a></li>
```

Comment: Have you tried to clear route?... `php artisan route:clear`...?

Comment: Yes. But still the same issue occur. I wonder why after I put the route for the view pages will cause this issue, but other route is no problem.

Comment: Is the route defined inside of a `Route::group();` ? Try `php artisan route:list` and see if the route is listed there.

Answer (score 0):

you need to give the route a name in order to use it via the `route` function

like below

```
Route::get('/reduce/{id}','ProductController@getReduceByOne')->name('product.reduceByOne');
```

then you can use it like below

`return redirect(route('product.reduceByOne'));`

in your case

```
<a href="{{ route('produce.reduceByOne') }}">Reduce by 1</a></li>
```

Comment: Try this method before. I think use 'as' => 'product.reduceByOne' should be same as name('product.reduceByOne') ?

Comment: what is the error message or the output you are getting? not working doesnt make any sense for us

Comment: It say 'Route [produce.reduceByOne] not defined. But I already set the route in web.php. But it show the error in my views page. When I tryied to applied <a href="{{ route('produce.reduceByOne') }}"></a> , it's cause the error